# JavaFX Packager creates redundant(?) .dll Files during build process

Tags: java, dll, javafx, deployment, exe

An Update of the JDK (to 8.92, but think it already changed in 8.40) caused the JavaFX Packager to create new .dll Files during the build prozess next to the generated .exe File. So after the build process the structure looks like the following:

/app
/runtime
Application.exe
Application.ico
msvcp120.dll
msvcr100.dll
msvcr120.dll
packager.dll

I am just curious and wonder, why these .dlls are necessary? We also include the runtime during the deployment process and within the runtime/bin Folder, there are the first three .dll files included as well. So it feels a bit redundant. Are they needed on system which dont have them installed on Windows32, so the .exe can still be launched? Could you point me to any documentation, which explains the purpose of these .dlls?